# How do I filter dates in VBA properly?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on automating the sorting process of filtering specific dates from a data.

I only want data that is under August 2018, but there are still a few dates which are not under the month of August.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SCRATCH").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "8/31/2018")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works, if the dates in your table are stored as date values (not as text).

Show all dates before a specific date, e. g. 1st of August 2018:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SCRATCH").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=10, _
    Criteria1:="<" & CDbl(CDate("8/1/2018"))
```

---

Show all dates within a timeframe between two dates, e. g. within August 2018:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SCRATCH").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=10, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(CDate("8/1/2018")), _
    Operator:=xlAnd, 
    Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(CDate("8/31/2018"))
```